# Wrong number or types of arguments error oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I created procedure under Program Units Oracle Forms

**Code:**

```
PROCEDURE VALIDATION_TEST
    (p_mid we_group_hof_k.mstatusid%TYPE,  
     p_status we_group_hof_k.cardstatus%TYPE
                       ) is
begin
  insert into test
  select mstatusid, cardstatus
   from we_group_hof_k
   where p_mid = 1
   and p_status = 'A';
end;
```

This procedure complies successfully. I put this line on When-Button-Pressed Trigger "TEST" Button

```
VALIDATION_TEST;
```

When I try to compile "TEST" Button then I am getting following error:

```
wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'VALIDATION_TEST'
```

I am using oracle forms 11g.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined your procedure with **two** parameters. Your call of that procedure passes **zero** parameters. So you solve this by passing **two** parameters when you call the procedure.

Or maybe by removing the parameters from the procedure's signature. Because quite frankly your code doesn't make a lot of sense. The WHERE clause tests the parameters against hardcoded values. So either you select all the records in `we_group_hof_k` - if the passed arguments are `1` and `'A'` - otherwise none.

Perhaps this is what you need?

```
PROCEDURE VALIDATION_TEST
    (p_mid we_group_hof_k.mstatusid%TYPE,  
     p_status we_group_hof_k.cardstatus%TYPE
                       ) is
begin
  insert into test
  select mstatusid, cardstatus
   from we_group_hof_k
   where mstatusid = p_mid 
   and cardstatus = p_status;
end;
```

Then you would call your procedure like this:

```
VALIDATION_TEST(1, 'A');
```

Although, as this procedure is called from Oracle Forms probably you need to pass in items from a Forms block. But only you know that for sure.

Comment: I have column with Condition where column IS NOT NULL. How to add in VALIDATION_TEST parameter

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what you mean. Is this related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55805735/146325)? But if you mean you want to add an additional `AND whatever IS NULL` criterion to the WHERE clause just do it. You don't need to change the signature of the procedure to do that.

Comment: If I add new parameter 3rd column then in select command how to write "AND column IS NOT NULL with 3rd parameter