# Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting on of the following Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have procedure under Program Units on Oracle Forms

**Code:**

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_TABLE

(p_mid we_group_hof_k.mstatusid%TYPE,  
 p_status we_group_hof_k.cardstatus%TYPE )

is    

begin
insert into test
select mstatusid, cardstatus
from we_group_hof_k
where mstatusid = p_mid 
and mstatusid = p_status;

end;
```

**Code under Button Trigger:**

```
INSERT_TABLE(1, IS NOT NULL);
```

When I compile Button Trigger then I am getting Following Error

```
"Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting on of the following"
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of the second parameter? Your INSERT statement has a WHERE clause which checks that `mstatusid = p_mid` and `mstatusid = p_status`. That second check is unnecessary. Consequently you don't need the second parameter.

Comment: I need this parameter with Validation check from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805735/how-to-check-conditions-and-write-text-into-text-file-oracle-forms/55807879#55807879. Check parameter IS NOT NULL then Write text Validation "OK" or "ERROR"

Comment: It seems your second parameter is of string type, and need to be wrapped up single quotes as `INSERT_TABLE(1,'IS NOT NULL')`

Comment: So this is (at least) the third question you have posted around this topic. The problem is , by atomising the task you have made it too hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. I suggest you post one question which includes all the different patterns of conditions (ie simplify it instead of all 15 if possible). Show all the combinations you're trying to test.